# Compiling with gcc causes the Docker build to fail

Tags: gcc, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to put together a Dockerfile so that I can run R and Python in the container. I am having issues when it comes to the `gcc` compilation portion of the script. I have included the Dockerfile that I am using below as well as the error I am getting when attempting to build the Docker image. I have run this code in a different Dockerfile and that container worked fine. I had to switch to a new image in order to get R and Python both in the environment, which ultimately led to this issue.

Any help or assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV ZHUNT_HOME=/zhunt
ARG GCC_OPTS="-lm"
ARG REQUIREMENTS=requirements.txt
ARG RREQUIREMENTS=install_packages.R

# Credit to
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437030/how-can-i-create-a-docker-image-to-run-both-python-and-r
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
                                               r-base \
                                               r-cran-randomforest \
                                               python3.6 \
                                               python3-pip \
                                               python3-setuptools \
                                               python3-dev \
                                               gcc
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Install all requirements.txt
# Copy zhunt source from build context
# Compile zhunt from source in this ubuntu environment

RUN mkdir -p $ZHUNT_HOME/bin\
    mkdir -p $ZHUNT_HOME/test\
    mkdir -p $ZHUNT_HOME/src

ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
#RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers

# python dependency installs
COPY $REQUIREMENTS $ZHUNT_HOME/$REQUIREMENTS
RUN python3 -m pip install -r $ZHUNT_HOME/$REQUIREMENTS

# R dependency installs
COPY $RREQUIREMENTS $ZHUNT_HOME/$RREQUIREMENTS
RUN Rscript $ZHUNT_HOME/$RREQUIREMENTS

# path changes
ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:$ZHUNT_HOME
ENV PATH $PATH:$ZHUNT_HOME/bin

# add source code and tests
COPY test $ZHUNT_HOME/test
COPY src $ZHUNT_HOME/src

# compile zhunt with gcc
RUN gcc -o $ZHUNT_HOME/bin/zhunt $ZHUNT_HOME/src/zhunt3.c
RUN gcc -o $ZHUNT_HOME/bin/mhunt $ZHUNT_HOME/src/mhunt.c

WORKDIR $ZHUNT_HOME

COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Error:

```
Step 19/23 : RUN gcc -o $ZHUNT_HOME/bin/zhunt $ZHUNT_HOME/src/zhunt3.c
 ---> Running in 1ac4082d2193
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o: in function `delta_linking':
zhunt3.c:(.text+0x24d): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: zhunt3.c:(.text+0x2cb): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o: in function `delta_linking_slope':
zhunt3.c:(.text+0x469): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: zhunt3.c:(.text+0x53d): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o: in function `assign_probability':
zhunt3.c:(.text+0xe77): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o:zhunt3.c:(.text+0x115d): more undefined references to `exp' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o: in function `find_delta_linking':
zhunt3.c:(.text+0x13a8): undefined reference to `log'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o: in function `calculate_zscore':
zhunt3.c:(.text+0x1681): undefined reference to `atan'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDfOmHG.o: in function `run_distribution':
zhunt3.c:(.text+0x2013): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c gcc -o $ZHUNT_HOME/bin/zhunt $ZHUNT_HOME/src/zhunt3.c' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-lm` is missing on this line (and possibly the next):

```
RUN gcc -o $ZHUNT_HOME/bin/zhunt $ZHUNT_HOME/src/zhunt3.c
```

When using functions from `<math.h>` such as `exp` and `atan`, it is necessary to link with the math library.

Comment: Okay, I added the lm flag and received the same error. As for the math library, that is included in my ".c" code already, unless I am missing something there

Comment: I had not, I had put it right after gcc (gcc -lm -o etc....) but moving it to the end of the command appeared to do the trick. Thanks Florian